# Z-index: make element go under its parent's sibling

Tags: html, css, z-index

Imagine this DOM:

```
<header>
    <h1> header </h1>
    <!-- other elements -->
    <nav>
        nav
    </nav>
</header>

<div>
    content
</div>
```

Both header and nav are positioned as `fixed`.
The content div is positioned as `relative`.
I need to create a stack, with z-index, in this order (from top to bottom):

- header *:not(nav)
- content
- nav

I'm having a hard time putting nav in the bottom (in other words, under its parent's sibling). I'm thinking that all header's children have to go either on top or under its sibling... is this right? If so, is there a workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only content that is "positioned" such as `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` or `position: relative` will respect the `z-index`.  As your HTML is structured, you can't do what you're asking for because parent/child is also respected so a child has to be in the parent (it can't be a completely different z-index vs. the parent).  To do what you want, you will have to break the `nav` out of the `header` and then they can each have their own `z-index`, one above and one below the default zero z-index of content.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't have to come to that, but I ended up breaking the nav out of the header.

Comment: **Only content that is position: absolute or position: fixed will respect the z-index.** 


This is so wrong.   
And here is a quot from https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/     
**First of all, z-index only works on positioned elements. If you try to set a z-index on an element with no position specified, it will do nothing. Secondly, z-index values can create stacking contexts, and now suddenly what seemed simple just got a lot more complicated.**

So ```position: relative``` is also works. Maybe others too.

Comment: @atilkan - I added `position: relative` to my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 You don't understand. You should read the quot. Again, it says. **z-index only works on positioned elements**. It has to be specified.

Comment: @atilkan - why don't you propose an edit?  I thought that is exactly what my first sentence says.

Comment: @jfriend00 But you had made more than adding ```position: relative```. I read it now and it looks good.

Comment: @atilkan - I made just one single edit yesterday to what it is now at you're suggestion so I'm not sure what you saw.  Anyway, glad we're good now.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround for this, with your DOM layout is to use negative z-index values. It is not highly recommend, though, to use negative value, just like its not recommended to use negative margin values.

A better solution would be to restructor your DOM. You may find [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-detailed-look-at-the-z-index-css-property/) useful. It explains the recommended ways of use the z-index property.

Hope this helps you!