# How to put main content under a fixed header?

Tags: html, css

For my class we have to work with positioning and nav bars. We currently have to recreate a photoshop image.

Requirements are the following: Put the navigation the the pink-ish header, put that header on a fixed position.

I know want to put content UNDER the header, [AKA leaving some space and then continue with the contents of the webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMa9k.png) I seem to have a hard time getting this "content box". How can I achieve this?

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(205, 99, 105);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigatie-midden li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

main {
  position: absolute
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navigatie-midden">
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Portfolio </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Archive </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  Content
</main>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z-index: make element go under its parent's sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429728/z-index-make-element-go-under-its-parents-sibling)

Comment: Remove absolute position from main and add 100px plus padding-top or margin-top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. All you needed was a top margin for `main`. I have added extra content so you can see how it functions when you can scroll. The content will disappear under the header.

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1366px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(205, 99, 105);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: solid 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigatie-midden li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

main {
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navigatie-midden">
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Portfolio </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Archive </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Content 1</p>
  <p>Content 2</p>
  <p>Content 3</p>
  <p>Content 4</p>
  <p>Content 5</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</main>
```